# Is it possible to rename every file in the system, that contains certain extension format?

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-extension, file-rename

Every popular known extension I have here on my system, is with a diferent extension format.
i.e: myfile.txt is now myfile.txt.sasa

I would like to remove the .sasa, so I came up with this:

FOR %%f IN (*.sasa) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"

Is there a way to make it look on the whole system, looking for files with extension .sasa and remove it from all of them?

EDIT:

Adding /r , seems to work. I tried it in a folder with subdirectories, and it worked like a charm.

@ECHO OFF
FOR /r %%f IN (*.sage) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"

I can't believe I forgot the /r in the first place. Anyway, maybe it will help someone else eventually.

Comment: Using `ForFiles` and `/s` for a recursive check? [ForFiles](https://ss64.com/nt/forfiles.html). Launch the command against the root of the drive you want to run it against and be patient. Also, brace yourself for some "access denied" scenarios. Recursively renaming files, from the Root down, will lead to your script trying to rename files in potentially protected areas.

Comment: But I wonder... how did your files get renamed in the first place? Is there a ransomware running loose on your machine? SO is not really the place for this discussion but, I'm curious. How did they get renamed in the first place?

Comment: Thanks for the answers, guys. I think that just adding the /r will do the job.                     I tried this: 
FOR /r %%f IN (*.sage) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"                                          I ran the .bat on a folder with subdirectories, and it seems to work. I'll try to run it on C:\. It all started with a ransomware.

Comment: I so did not want to be right about the ransomware! Just so you know, merely renaming the files will not give you back your content. A ransomware will "encrypt" the content of your files [AND rename them]. To get the content back, you'll need to break the encryption or pay the ransom and hope for the best. Or, best of all, reinstate your last backup. But who's got backups?

Comment: You found the solution yourself, so please post your own answer instead of including it in your question...

Comment: Luckly, most of the files are working fine. I did lost some txt, zip, and doc files that I had some usefull stuff saved, but I had a backup on clould for most of them, so...that was a relief. I have a lot of .iso  and .jpeg files that were not encrypted, just renamed with the addition of .sasa extension.

Answer (score 1):

I found this command very useful in this scenario. Worked like a charm:

FOR /r %%f IN (*.sasa) DO RENAME "%%f" "%%~nf"

I would like to thank everyone for the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
CALL :loop

:loop
for %%f in (*.txt.sasa) do rename %%f %%f.txt
for /D %%d in (*) do (
    cd %%d
    echo %%d
    CALL :loop
    cd ..
)
EXIT /B
```

Recursively iterate throught each file of every directory and rename the files to your desired name.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that trough the command line.

1.Press Shift and right-click on the folder and select "Open Command Window Here".

[image]

2. You will now see a Command Window with the current folderdirectory open. Now type the following command line

[image]

Comment: How will this recurse into subdirectories?

Comment: For the sake of people who can't resolve images, can the command not be added to your answer as text?

Comment: try: FOR /R "C:\path\to\Folder" %f IN (*.sasa) DO REN "%f" *.txt

Comment: This not works. Your `ren *.sasa *.txt` command just change the `.sasa` extension by a `.txt` one, so an original `myfile.txt.sasa` file ends as `myfile.txt.txt`, but a `document.doc.sasa` one ends as `document.doc.txt`!